# Nuxt parent component is being rendered below child component

Tags: routes, nuxt.js

Here is the repository https://github.com/yiyasha15/nuxt_routes_issue to reproduce the issue (Please refer README.md file).

1. Navigate to the user card.
2. The _id page is the parent component and I'm sending the 'user' object to the 'work' component.
3. Go to work page, the _id page will render below it.

How do I stop rendering the parent component below the child component?
Thanks.

Comment: Hey yiyisha. I've gone through your code and it seems to be perfect to me. What you are currently doing is to use the _id.vue page as a parent. The work page is being rendered as a nuxt-child (that you have mentioned in the _id.vue page). This behavior is completely OK. :) Do let me know in case you need further explanation.

Comment: hey, thanks for checking it out, but actually i don't want _id.vue page to render when i'm on work page. how do i achieve that? @Helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that i was calling the child page(work page) inside parent page(_id.vue) and hence child was getting rendered( along with parent page (expected behavior). I made an index page inside the _id folder and put my _id content there.

So now _id and work pages content and rendered accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refer this:

[image]

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing/

What you need to do is to just introduce few changes in the file locations for nuxt to generate the correct route that suits your scenario the best. Do let me know in case I wasn't good enough to explain.